# Calculate a Kind of Equivalent Baseband Signal by Examining the Zero Crossing

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, modulation, phase

I have a device (whose behaviour I can't change) which does the following signal processing:

The incomming signal contains two frequencies $f_1$ and $f_2$. One has a huge amplitude, the other a smaller one:

$x_1 = X_{01} \cdot cos(2\pi f_1 \cdot t)$

$x_2 = X_{02} \cdot cos(2\pi f_2 \cdot t)$

with (for example):

$f_1 = 20.02e6, f_2 = 20e6, X_{01} >> X_{02}$ (Actually $f_2$ is an interfering signal).

An example for this signal (only the beating envelope is visible) is depicted below.
[image: time signal]

At first, phase durations are calculated by "measuring" the duration between two zero crossings. Then the phase duration of $f_1$ is subtracted - so if $f_2$ wouldn't be there, the phase duration signal would always be zero.
But since there is $f_2$ also, the phase duration signal contains a new periodic signal, beeing periodic with $f = f_1-f_2 = 20kHz$. I get the following signal:
[image: phase signal - complete]
With zoom
[image: phase signal - zoom]

My problem is: This signal is not a pure sine wave but it contains some additional frequencies - as already visible in the zoomed phase signal. The DFT shows the containing frequencies (which are harmonics). They are depicted below.
[image: DFT of the complete phase signal]

Does anyone know an equation for the amplitudes of those frequencies as a function of the amplitude and frequency of $X_{01}$ and $X_{02}$?

To make it more complex, I unfortunaly have a second interfering signal at $f_3=19.08e6$. Is there an equation for this case, too?

Comment: Why are you doing the zero-crossing math? Is your aim to suppress the interference, measure its characteristics, etc.?

Comment: This zero-crossing math is done in the measurement card of an heterodyne michelson interferometer.The interferometer measures the speed of a measuremnt object which does influence $f_1$ (via Doppler effect) - and so the displacement is shown in the phase of the $f_1$-signal. So the aim is to measure the change in phase which is done via zero-crossing. In my example above there is no change in phase because I want to keep it as simple as possible. The interference signal $f_2$ results of improper optics (which can't be changed). One problem I have to deal with is $f_2$ and its harmonics.